# WinSCP - Rename file in a directory, where listing/browsing is forbidden

Tags: ftp, winscp

I'm moving to using `WinSCP.com` over `FTP.exe` due to it's capabilities of being able to use PASSIVE mode.  I have started to convert my FTP script to WinSCP and noticed something that is happening and I don't have a solution for.

**Current script - (ftpcommands.txt)**

```
open ftp://user:pass@ftp.host.com/
cd /
put -transfer=binary "C:\Users\username\Desktop\test folder\myfile.7z.uploading"
mv "myfile.7z.uploading" "myfile.7z"
bye
```

**Calling it from console window**

```
Bin\WinSCP.com /script="ftpcommands.txt" /ini=nul
```

**Console window results**

```
Connecting to ftp.host.com ...
Connected
Starting the session...
Session started.
Active session: [1] user@ftp.host.com
/
myfile.7z.uploading       |         193 KB |  754.8 KB/s | binary | 100%
Can't get attributes of file 'myfile.7z.uploading'.
Could not retrieve file information
Permission denied.
```

**WinSCP log file (when using the /log=winscp.log switch)**

```
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.432 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.432 WinSCP Version 5.13.3 (Build 8565) (OS 10.0.17134 - Windows 10 Enterprise)
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.432 Configuration: nul
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.432 Log level: Normal
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.432 Local account: GALAXY\username
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.432 Working directory: C:\Users\username\Desktop\test folder
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.432 Process ID: 30844
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.432 Command-line: "C:\Users\username\Desktop\test folder\Bin\WinSCP.exe" /console=5.13.3 /consoleinstance=_18928_436 "/script=Logs\ftpcommands.txt" "/ini=nul" "/log=winscp.log" 
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.432 Time zone: Current: GMT-4, Standard: GMT-5 (Eastern Standard Time), DST: GMT-4 (Eastern Daylight Time), DST Start: 3/11/2018, DST End: 11/4/2018
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.510 Login time: Thursday, August 9, 2018 1:09:43 PM
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.510 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.510 Script: Retrospectively logging previous script records:
> 2018-08-09 13:09:43.510 Script: open ftp://user:***@ftp.host.com/
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.510 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.510 Session name: user@ftp.host.com (Ad-Hoc site)
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.510 Host name: ftp.host.com (Port: 21)
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.510 User name: user (Password: Yes, Key file: No, Passphrase: No)
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.510 Transfer Protocol: FTP
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.510 Ping type: Dummy, Ping interval: 30 sec; Timeout: 15 sec
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.510 Disable Nagle: No
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.510 Proxy: None
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.510 Send buffer: 262144
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.510 UTF: Auto
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.510 FTPS: None [Client certificate: No]
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.510 FTP: Passive: Yes [Force IP: Auto]; MLSD: Auto [List all: Auto]; HOST: Auto
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.510 Local directory: default, Remote directory: home, Update: Yes, Cache: Yes
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.510 Cache directory changes: Yes, Permanent: Yes
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.510 Recycle bin: Delete to: No, Overwritten to: No, Bin path: 
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.510 Timezone offset: 0h 0m
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.510 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.510 Connecting to ftp.host.com ...
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.573 Connected with ftp.host.com. Waiting for welcome message...
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.588 220-Welcome
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.588 220-
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.588 220-Company FTP Server
> 2018-08-09 13:09:43.588 USER user
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.620 331 Password required for user
> 2018-08-09 13:09:43.620 PASS ****
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.635 230 Logged on
> 2018-08-09 13:09:43.635 SYST
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.651 215 UNIX emulated by FileZilla
> 2018-08-09 13:09:43.651 FEAT
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.682 211-Features:
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.682  MDTM
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.698  REST STREAM
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.698  SIZE
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.698  MLST type*;size*;modify*;
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.698  MLSD
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.698  AUTH SSL
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.698  AUTH TLS
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.698  PROT
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.698  PBSZ
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.698  UTF8
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.698  CLNT
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.698  MFMT
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.698  EPSV
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.698  EPRT
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.698 211 End
> 2018-08-09 13:09:43.698 CLNT WinSCP-release-5.13.3
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.698 200 Don't care
> 2018-08-09 13:09:43.698 OPTS UTF8 ON
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.713 202 UTF8 mode is always enabled. No need to send this command.
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.713 Connected
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.713 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.713 Using FTP protocol.
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.713 Doing startup conversation with host.
> 2018-08-09 13:09:43.713 PWD
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.729 257 "/" is current directory.
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.729 Getting current directory name.
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.729 Startup conversation with host finished.
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.729 Script: Active session: [1] user@ftp.host.com
> 2018-08-09 13:09:43.746 Script: cd /
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.746 Changing directory to "/".
> 2018-08-09 13:09:43.746 CWD /
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.767 250 CWD successful. "/" is current directory.
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.767 Getting current directory name.
> 2018-08-09 13:09:43.767 PWD
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.787 257 "/" is current directory.
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.787 Script: /
> 2018-08-09 13:09:43.787 Script: put -transfer=binary "C:\Users\username\Desktop\test folder\myfile.7z.uploading"
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.787 Copying 1 files/directories to remote directory "/" - total size: 198,017
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.787   PrTime: Yes; PrRO: No; Rght: rw-r--r--; PrR: No (No); FnCs: N; RIC: 0100; Resume: S (102400); CalcS: No; Mask: 
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.787   TM: B; ClAr: No; RemEOF: No; RemBOM: No; CPS: 0; NewerOnly: No; InclM: ; ResumeL: 0
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.787   AscM: *.*html; *.htm; *.txt; *.php; *.php3; *.cgi; *.c; *.cpp; *.h; *.pas; *.bas; *.tex; *.pl; *.js; .htaccess; *.xtml; *.css; *.cfg; *.ini; *.sh; *.xml
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.787 File: 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\test folder\myfile.7z.uploading' [2018-08-09T15:41:57.040Z] [198017]
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.787 Copying "C:\Users\username\Desktop\test folder\myfile.7z.uploading" to remote directory started.
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.787 Binary transfer mode selected.
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.787 Starting upload of C:\Users\username\Desktop\test folder\myfile.7z.uploading
> 2018-08-09 13:09:43.787 TYPE I
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.803 200 Type set to I
> 2018-08-09 13:09:43.803 PASV
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.818 227 Entering Passive Mode (1,2,3,4,17,147)
> 2018-08-09 13:09:43.818 STOR myfile.7z.uploading
. 2018-08-09 13:09:43.818 Connecting to 1.2.3.4:4499 ...
< 2018-08-09 13:09:43.865 150 Opening data channel for file upload to server of "/myfile.7z.uploading"
< 2018-08-09 13:09:44.084 226 Successfully transferred "/myfile.7z.uploading"
> 2018-08-09 13:09:44.084 MFMT 20180809154157 myfile.7z.uploading
< 2018-08-09 13:09:44.100 550 Permission denied
. 2018-08-09 13:09:44.100 Upload successful
. 2018-08-09 13:09:44.100 Transfer done: 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\test folder\myfile.7z.uploading' => '/myfile.7z.uploading' [198017]
. 2018-08-09 13:09:44.100 Copying finished: Transferred: 198,017, Elapsed: 0:00:00, CPS: 776,209/s
> 2018-08-09 13:09:44.100 Script: mv "myfile.7z.uploading" "myfile.7z"
. 2018-08-09 13:09:44.100 Listing file "myfile.7z.uploading".
. 2018-08-09 13:09:44.100 Retrieving file information...
> 2018-08-09 13:09:44.100 MLST /myfile.7z.uploading
< 2018-08-09 13:09:44.131 550 Permission denied.
. 2018-08-09 13:09:44.131 Could not retrieve file information
< 2018-08-09 13:09:44.131 Script: Can't get attributes of file 'myfile.7z.uploading'.
< 2018-08-09 13:09:44.131 Could not retrieve file information

< 2018-08-09 13:09:44.131 Permission denied.
. 2018-08-09 13:09:44.131 Script: Failed
. 2018-08-09 13:09:44.131 Script: Exit code: 1
. 2018-08-09 13:09:44.131 Disconnected from server
```

I can connect to the FTP server, login, send the single file.  That part works great.  Then after I send the file I was hoping to get a `226 Successfully transferred` message shown to my console window.  Instead I have a message showing the following...

> Can't get attributes of file 'MyFileName.txt'.

I have my FTP server set up in a way that the only access rights given are...

- Write
- Delete

There are no type of read or list rights given to the user.  The idea is to have this script blindly dump a file to the FTP server, check that the FTP server returns a successful `226` message and then blindly rename the file once it has been uploaded.

Everything works great with `FTP.exe` but for some reason I can't get it to work for `WinSCP.com`.  So this leaves me with two questions...

1. Is it possible to show the actual server responses when using `WinSCP.com`?
2. Is it possible to turn off the way `WinSCP.com` trys to read things like attributes and file information after an upload?

Comment: Can you enable logging (`/log=winscp.log`) and include a log file into the question?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl sure, it has been added.  Thanks.

Comment: Weird...  I wonder why someone voted to close the question.  They didn't even leave a reason why.  I think it's a valid question for SO.  There are MANY questions (~3,393) just like mine on SO about WinSCP.

Comment: OK, so it's the rename that fails. I assume, that it's by purpose that you upload the file using a temporary file name, right? As a workaround, cannot you upload the file to a folder, where listing is enabled; and only after a successful upload, move it to the final folder (where listing is forbidden)?

Comment: I voted to move it to SuperUser as your problem really has nothing to do with programming.  It is an application specific or permissions problem in my experience.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I would rather that not be the case.  I will have the same user account being used by 100's of users and sending in similar files.  Because of the fact that RENAME requires `DELETE` access all users would have access to play wack a mole with all the files that have been uploaded.  This defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to do.  Maybe some type of `site` or `quote` command could be used to bypass WinSCP's logic and just rename it myself.

Comment: @Squashman Thanks for adding the comment it helps when people give you bad marks.  I understand and might agree to some extent.  But this is somewhat scripting which is a form of coding.  And like I pointed out before, SO is home to over 3,000 other WinSCP related questions.

Comment: @ArvoBowen, can we at least agree then to remove the batch-file tag as your scripting problem is with WinSCP and not related to any actual Windows Batch-file code?

Comment: @Squashman agreed and done.  Thanks!

Comment: @MartinPrikryl also, something else I forgot to mention, the `MFMT` command received before the `550 Permission denied` is not from the rename.  It's from the internal WinSCP process of trying to check the contents of the directory after it uploads a file.  Kinda like a double check.  But I think I might have a solution shortly...  Doing some testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot prevent WinSCP from checking file before doing rename.

But as you have hinted yourself, you can workaround it using [WinSCP `call` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_call) and FTP commands `RNFR` and `RNTO`:

```
call RNFR myfile.7z.uploading
call RNTO myfile.7z
```

---

As for the `MFMT`, WinSCP uses that to update a timestamp of the uploaded file. If that fails, WinSCP silently ignores the error.

But if you want to avoid having the error in the log file, just use [`-nopreservetime` switch of the `put` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put#nopreservetime).

Comment: I was just about to get back to this and submit an answer but you beat me to it.  This is EXACTLY the information I needed to answer both of my questions.  Spot on Martin, thanks!